# In Ansible, how can I access a "number of disks" variable?

Tags: hadoop, yaml, ansible

I'm looking into tuning MapR Hadoop via Ansible templates.

It is easy enough to tune something to the number of CPU threads found on a system.   For example, to set reduce tasks to 1/4 of threads:

```
<name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
<value>{{ (ansible_processor_vcpus / 4)|int }}</value>
```

One resource suggests that the number of map / reduce tasks should be scaled to the number of **disks** on the system.  I don't see any comparable variable for that.

There is an array of `ansible_devices` with sda, sdb, &c.  Perhaps I can count that?  Perhaps apply a filter so I'm only counting disks which are available to Hadoop?

Comment: obHadoop: double-check your resource constraints at peak.  There are general recommendations but your environment may be CPU constrained vs disk ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe [length](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#length):

```
<name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
<value>{{ (ansible_devices|length) / 4 }}</value>
```